# (530, '5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 135sm7372342lfb.28 - gsmtp',u'mail id)

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to send mail using `django`, and I'm getting this error :

```
(530, '5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 135sm7372342lfb.28 - gsmtp',u'mail id)******
```

Can someone help?.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

to your settings page where you have all your email settings. Also make sure that your gmail SMTP has the right login details and make sure that Django is using SMTP mail server.